# php generated Security code image

Tags: php, html, session

I use sessions for generating an image by a seccode.php file. And i add 
img src='seccode.php'
in my sign in page. It works well but sometimes that user want to use sign in page more than one times it shows image of last generated session. I use firebug and see that image in img tag is right but image that shows on browser is wrong. browser always show last generated security code.
I want browser shows current generated image.
any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You might add a random number to the image generated as a query string, so the browser won't use the cached version instead.

```
<?php
$rand = rand(5,10);  //or a random string, whatever suits you
?>
<img src="seccode.php?r=<?php echo $rand;?>" />
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the browser is still going to cache it and the cache is going to end up having multiple security images cached.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a cache issue. Add these http headers to the top of your seccode.php file to prevent the browser from caching it.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```